# C# Win Forms: Get Login username and save to string, from simple SQL login and call this string in new form

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I'm making a program to ease the overview of certain functions. I currently have the program split up into 3 Forms. A login form, using a very simple SQL login, the mainwindow and then a "New Site" window.

I would like to grab the login from Form1 and pass it to Form2.

Firstly because I would like this value to get returned by a label and also to later create a show/hide administrate users button and to restrict editing to one class of users.

I've tried saving it as a public static int, but this doesnt return anything in my new main form.

Here's the first form;

```
namespace AvOverview{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string value1 = string.Empty;
    public string Value1
    {
        get { return value1; }
        set { value1 = value; }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_Password.PasswordChar = '*';
    }
    //Connection String 
    string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf";
    //btn_Submit Click event

    private void Button_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_UserName.Text == "" || txt_Password.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide Username and Password");
            return;
        }
         try
        {
            //Create SqlConnection

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Login where UserName=@username and Password=@password", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt_UserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_Password.Text);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(ds);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            //If count is equal to 1, then show frmMain form
            if (count == 1)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
                this.Hide();
                FrmMain fm = new FrmMain();
                fm.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}}
```

And here's the second form, if you need it;

```
namespace AvOverview{
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //btn_LogOut Click Event
        this.Hide();
        Form1 fl = new Form1();
        fl.Show();
    }

    private void FrmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //SQLconnection string
        string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf";

        //SQLconnection
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        string strCmd = "select * from AvSites";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //Fill combobox list with items from the SQL database
        da.Fill(ds);
        combo1.ValueMember = "id";
        combo1.DisplayMember = "siteName";
        combo1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        combo1.Enabled = true;
        this.combo1.SelectedItem = -1;
        this.combo1.SelectedText = "--select--";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }

    private void Combo1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Populate Textboxes with data from each entry in the SQLdb
        DataRowView rv = combo1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if (rv != null)
        {
            txt_siteName.Text = rv[2].ToString();
            txt_siteProjnr.Text = rv[1].ToString();
            txt_siteManaip.Text = rv[5].ToString();
            txt_ManPass.Text = rv[6].ToString();
            txt_txtmanAvpass.Text = rv[8].ToString();
            txt_manAvusr.Text = rv[7].ToString();
            txt_siteClients.Text = rv[4].ToString();
            txt_siteLicenses.Text = rv[3].ToString();
            txt_siteLicenseExpi.Text = rv[9].ToString();
            txt_siteManUsr.Text = rv[12].ToString();
            txt_siteID.Text = rv[0].ToString();
            txt_siteAvMove.Text = rv[10].ToString();
            txt_siteAvTools.Text = rv[11].ToString();

        }
    }

    private void Chkbox_showHide_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show/Hide password text in Manager Textbox
        if (chkbox_showHide.Checked)
        {
            txt_ManPass.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        }
        else
        {
            txt_ManPass.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;

            //txt_ManPass.PasswordChar = chkbox_showHide.Checked ? '\0' : '*';
        }
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form3 fm2 = new Form3();
        fm2.Show();
    }

    private void Chkbox_showHide2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show/Hide password text in Manager Textbox
        if (chkbox_showHide2.Checked)
        {
            txt_txtmanAvpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        }
        else
        {
            txt_txtmanAvpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;

        }
    }

    private void TxtClip1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Copy textbox to clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(txt_ManPass.Text);
    }

    private void TxtClip2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Copy textbox to clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(txt_txtmanAvpass.Text);
    }
    private void BtnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = txt_siteName.Text; 
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to edit " + test, "You are about to update a site!" ,MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf";

            //SQLconnection
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

            con.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE AvSites SET projectNr=@ProjectNr, siteName=@siteName, siteLicenses=@siteLicenses, siteClients=@siteClients, siteManagerIP=@siteManagerIP, siteManagerPassword=@siteManagerPassword, siteManagerAvUser=@siteManagerAvUser, SiteManagerAvPass=@SiteManagerAvPass, siteLicenseExpi=@siteLicenseExpi, siteAvMove=@siteAvMove, siteAvTools=@siteAvTools, siteManagerUser=@siteManagerUser WHERE id=@id";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectNr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteProjnr.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteClients", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteClients.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteLicenses", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteLicenses.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteManagerIP", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteManaip.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteManagerPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_ManPass.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteManagerAvUser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_manAvusr.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteManagerAvPass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_txtmanAvpass.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteLicenseExpi", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteLicenseExpi.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteManagerUser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteManUsr.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteAvMove", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteAvMove.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteAvTools", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteAvTools.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_siteID.Text; //invisible textbox we use this to determine the site
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();


            FrmMain fm2 = new FrmMain();
            fm2.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            //do nothing
        }

    }

    private void TxtClip3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(txt_siteManUsr.Text);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming you want to pass data from Form1 to FrmMain (at least this are the 2 classes you are showing us here). What you should do is a new constructor of the FrmMain class like this:

```
public FrmMain(string username, string password)
{
//do whatever you want with those variables
}
```

And in the Form one instead of calling

```
FrmMain fm = new FrmMain();
```

you should call

```
FrmMain fm = new FrmMain(txt_UserName.Text, txt_Password.Text);
```